# Magento: Get record of my model by custom Field

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Is it possible to get a record of my model by another field of my model?

The normal way

```
$model = Mage::getModel('foo_bar/baz');
$model->load($id);
// do something with the loaded record
```

But i need something like this

```
$model = Mage::getModel('foo_bar/baz');
$model->loadByAnotherFieldOfModel($value)
// do something with the loaded record
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('foo_bar/baz');
$model->load('field_value', 'field_name');
```

Comment: Okey that's to easy and to smart :D

Comment: What if multiple row match the same field data ? For me its only returning one row or one record ? Is there a way to return the collection of rows matched the field data.

Comment: @OSdave, Could you please replace $id with some meaningful variable name eg: $fieldName, just to clear up confusion.  $model->load($fieldName, 'field_name');

Comment: @vineetsajwan, you got it wrong. $id is the value that 'field_name' field should have, in order to load that record.

Comment: @Mihai - Ok, actually I understood that way.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'computer');  
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('name', 'hp2312');  

// Load by SKU  
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'computer123');
```

Comment: don't forget to like my answer if it was helpful .

Answer (score 1):

Goto model file

```
NameSpace/Yourmodule/Model/YourModel.php
```

add below code

```
public function loadByField($fieldvalue)
{
  $this->_getResource()->loadByField($this, $fieldvalue);
  return $this;
}
```

AND

```
NameSpace/YourModule/Model/Resource/YourModel.php
```

and code is

```
public function loadByField(NameSpace_YourModule_Model_YourModel $Object, $fieldvalue)
{
  $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
  $bind    = array('fieldname' => $fieldvalue);
  $select  = $adapter->select()
      ->from($this->getMainTable(), 'tablePrimaryKey')
      ->where('fieldname = :fieldname');

  $modelId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
  if ($modelId) {
    $this->load($Object, $modelId );
  } else {
    $Object->setData(array());
  }

  return $this;
}
```

Comment: This work fine but I think the solution of @osdave is the more "best practice way"